# Error during ATI propreitary driver install

Tags: 12.10, radeon

I tried to install the latest (13.1) ATI propreitary drivers, as mentioned [here](http://wiki.cchtml.com/index.php/Ubuntu_Quantal_Installation_Guide#Installing_Catalyst_Manually_.28from_AMD.2FATI.27s_site.29).

But I'm getting the following error when trying to create .deb packages for use.

```
.........
.........
# refresh copyright file
cat debian/copyright_stub_0 > debian/copyright
cat usr/share/doc/fglrx/LICENSE.TXT >> debian/copyright
cat debian/copyright_stub_1 >> debian/copyright
#Steps that we can't easily represent in debhelper files or .in files yet
# Remove any libraries that may be caught by shell expansion
find . -name libGLE* | xargs rm -f
find . -name libEGL* | xargs rm -f
dh_installdirs -pfglrx
# Install the QT libraries
dh_install -pfglrx "arch/x86_64/usr/share/ati/lib" "usr/share/ati"
cp: cannot stat `debian/tmp/arch/x86_64/usr/share/ati/lib': No such file or directory
dh_install: cp -a debian/tmp/arch/x86_64/usr/share/ati/lib debian/fglrx/usr/share/ati/ returned exit code 1
make: *** [binary-arch] Error 2
dpkg-buildpackage: error: debian/rules binary gave error exit status 2
[Error] Generate Package - error generating package : Ubuntu/quantal
```

How can I fix this error?

I tried the open Radeon driver, but the laptop was overheating to above 80 degrees C.

I installed the propreitary drivers via the Software Sources window, and the system was running at moderate temperature, but then I couldn't login to Gnome 3 after the reboot, so installing the propreitary drivers properly would be really useful.

Comment: For now,I've added the Xorg edgers PPA and installed the open drivers (found at http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/ppa/xorg-edgers). The temps still rise to 70 degrees C, but at least it's less than the 80 earlier, and Gnome 3 works.

Answer (score 0):

From what I read over on [ubuntufourms](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2099793&p=12454945#post12454945) it is a bug in the package installer. To fix it

1. Extract the package with `$sh ./amd-driver-installer-catalyst-12.11-beta11-x86.x86_64.run --extract ~/build/amd-v12.11`
2. Go to the file relative to the above extracted dir: `packages/Ubuntu/dists/quantal`
3. Edit the file `rules`.

On line 242 the text
`dh_install -p$(PKG_driver) "arch/x86_64/usr/share/ati/lib" "$(datadir)/ati"` should read `dh_install -p$(PKG_driver) "arch/x86/usr/share/ati/lib" "$(datadir)/ati"`

As you can see it is just an assumption that is made about this script always being run on 64 bit machines.

(Similar fix for other Ubuntus, just fix the `packages/Ubuntu/dists/<release>` path above.)